# DB2 issue Getting -101 for 300 records but same query working for 1000 and 10000 records

Tags: sql, db2

I am facing strange issue in Db2 .
I am getting DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -101, SQLSTATE: 54001, SQLERRMC: 1
The same query works for 1000 even 10000 records but does not works for particualar sets of records(150-300).I am able to reproduce now with those records.
Query uses Select and With cause only.
So I donot think increasing STMT Heap Memory will make any sense as the query works for larger records.
Query is Big and Consists of only Select Join and few Case statement.
Query is also using With statement.
@Note Every Record is independent in its own have relation with another record.

Here is Query

```
WITH
itemStyle_ AS (
    SELECT * FROM item.itemStyle WHERE itemSTY_SEQ 
---- This Parameter gets changes to 1000 only 
IN( 'awudhjqwdvwd12'  )


),CustomsInfo AS
(SELECT 3 AS ReitemrtGrp, 3 AS REitemRTGRP2, HSYS_NO, NHSYS_NO, itemCUSTOMSINFO.itemDEL_SEQ,-1 AS COL_NO,
        itemStyle.MyApp_item_NO, itemStyle.SIZE_TNAME, itemStyle.CS_DATE, itemStyle.SIZ1TABID, itemDELIVERY.DS_NO,
itemStyle.ABM_Date, itemStyle.RS_Date,itemStyle.CustCo_NO, itemStyle.Cust_Code, itemStyle.UCustCo_No, itemStyle.Prodiv_desc, itemStyle.Busunidesc,itemStyle.COno, itemStyle.STY_NO
    FROM item.itemCUSTOMSINFO itemCUSTOMSINFO INNER JOIN item.itemDELIVERY itemDELIVERY ON itemCUSTOMSINFO.itemDEL_SEQ = itemDELIVERY.itemDEL_SEQ, itemStyle_ itemStyle
        WHERE (HSYS_NO IS NOT NULL OR NHSYS_NO IS NOT NULL)
            AND itemCUSTOMSINFO.itemSTY_SEQ = itemStyle.itemSTY_SEQ
            ),
SizeInfo AS(
SELECT  1 AS ReitemrtGrp2,
    itemStyle.SIZ1TABID, itemDELCOLOR.itemDEL_SEQ, itemStyle.MyApp_item_NO, itemStyle.CS_DATE, itemStyle.STY_NO,
    itemStyle.ABM_Date, itemStyle.RS_Date,itemStyle.CustCo_NO, itemStyle.Cust_Code, itemStyle.UCustCo_No, itemStyle.Prodiv_desc, itemStyle.Busunidesc,itemStyle.COno,itemDELCOLOR.DS_NO,
    itemColor.COL_NO,CUSIZ_CODE,
    itemDELSIZE.QUANTITY,itemDELSIZE.OCP_FACTOR,itemDELSIZE.SKU_CODE,
    itemSIZE.SIZE_CODE, itemSIZE.UNIT_PRC,itemSIZE.SURCHARGE,itemSIZE.SIZNUM itemSIZE_NUM, itemSIZE.UNIT_DISC, itemSIZE.PACK_UNIT
FROM
    itemStyle_ AS itemStyle
    INNER JOIN item.itemColor  itemColor ON itemStyle.itemSTY_SEQ = itemColor.itemSTY_SEQ
    INNER JOIN item.itemDELCOLOR itemDELCOLOR ON itemDELCOLOR.itemCOL_SEQ = itemColor.itemCOL_SEQ
    INNER JOIN item.itemDELSIZE itemDELSIZE ON itemDELCOLOR.itemDELCOL_SEQ = itemDELSIZE.itemDELCOL_SEQ
    INNER JOIN item.itemSIZE itemSIZE ON itemDELSIZE.itemSIZ_SEQ = itemSIZE.itemSIZ_SEQ
),OrderChar AS(
   SELECT 3 AS ReitemrtGrp2, 2.6 AS ReitemrtGrp,
   ordchar_desc, itemStyle.COno, CS_Date, SIZ1TABID, itemStyle.MyApp_item_NO, itemStyle.STY_NO,
itemStyle.ABM_Date, itemStyle.RS_Date,itemStyle.CustCo_NO, itemStyle.Cust_Code, itemStyle.UCustCo_No, itemStyle.Prodiv_desc, itemStyle.Busunidesc,itemDELIVERY.itemDEL_SEQ  FROM
   item.itemORDERCHAR itemOrderChar INNER JOIN itemStyle_ itemStyle ON itemOrderChar.itemSty_Seq = itemStyle.itemSty_Seq
   INNER JOIN item.itemDELIVERY itemDELIVERY ON itemStyle.itemSTY_SEQ = itemDELIVERY.itemSTY_SEQ
),
Supp_Address AS (
SELECT ADDRESS.COMPANY1 AS SuppAdd_COMPANY1,
    ADDRESS.COMPANY2 AS SuppAdd_COMPANY2,
    ADDRESS.COMPANY3 AS SuppAdd_COMPANY3,
    ADDRESS.STREET1 AS SuppAdd_STREET1,
    ADDRESS.STREET2 AS SuppAdd_STREET2,
    ADDRESS.STREET3 AS SuppAdd_STREET3,
    ADDRESS.CITY AS SuppAdd_CITY,
    ADDRESS.STATENAME AS SuppAdd_STATENAME,
    ADDRESS.COUNTRY AS SuppAdd_COUNTRY,
    ADDRESS.ZIP_CODE AS SuppAdd_ZIP_CODE,
        SUPPLIER.SUP1COMID,
        CONTACTINF.C_PHONENO, CONTACTINF.A_PHONENO, CONTACTINF.M_PHONE ,
        ADDRESS.ZitemST_BOX , ADDRESS.itemST_BOX
FROM item.ADDRESS ADDRESS,
        item.ORGANZN ORGANZN
        LEFT OUTER JOIN item.SUPPLIER SUPPLIER
        ON      ORGANZN.ORG_ID=SUPPLIER.ORG_ID,
                item.CONTACTINF CONTACTINF WHERE
        (                ADDRESS.ORG_ID=ORGANZN.ORG_ID        )    AND
        (                CONTACTINF.ADDRESS_ID=ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID        )    AND
        (
                SUPPLIER.SUPP_FLAG = 'Y'
        )) ,
Cust_Address AS (
    SELECT  VALUE(ADDRESS.COMPANY1,'') CustAdd_COMPANY1 ,
        VALUE(ADDRESS.COMPANY2,'') AS CustAdd_COMPANY2,
        VALUE(ADDRESS.COMPANY3,'') AS CustAdd_COMPANY3,
        VALUE(ADDRESS.STREET1,'')  AS CustAdd_STREET1,
        VALUE(ADDRESS.STREET2,'')  AS CustAdd_STREET2,
        VALUE(ADDRESS.STREET3 ,'') AS CustAdd_STREET3,
        VALUE(ADDRESS.CITY,'')     AS CustAdd_CITY,
        VALUE(ADDRESS.STATENAME,'') AS CustAdd_STATENAME,
        VALUE(ADDRESS.COUNTRY ,'') AS CustAdd_COUNTRY,
        VALUE(ADDRESS.ZIP_CODE ,'')AS  CustAdd_ZIPCODE,
        VALUE(CUSTOMER.CUST_ID ,'')AS CustAdd_CUST_ID,
        VALUE(ADDRESS.ZitemST_BOX,'') AS CustAdd_ZitemST_BOX ,
        VALUE(ADDRESS.itemST_BOX,'') AS CustAdd_itemST_BOX
FROM    item.ADDRESS ADDRESS,
        item.CUSTOMER CUSTOMER
        LEFT OUTER JOIN item.ORGANZN ORGANZN
        ON      ORGANZN.ORG_ID=CUSTOMER.ORG_ID,
                item.ORGDEFAULTS ORGDEFAULTSWHERE
        (                ADDRESS.ORG_ID=ORGANZN.ORG_ID        )
    AND        (
                ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID=ORGDEFAULTS.DEFAULT_VALUE_ID        )    AND
        (                CUSTOMER.CUST_FLAG='Y'        )
    AND ORGDEFAULTS.DEFAULT_ITEM = 'MAILING_ADDRESS'
SELECT  VALUE(CustomsInfo.ReitemrtGrp, OrderChar.ReitemrtGrp, 3) AS ReitemrtGrp,
    VALUE(SizeInfo.ReitemrtGrp2,  OrderChar.ReitemrtGrp2, CustomsInfo.ReitemrtGrp2, 4) AS ReitemrtGrp2,
    VALUE(itemStyle.MyApp_item_NO, CUSTOMSINFO.MyApp_item_NO, SizeInfo.MyApp_item_NO,OrderChar .MyApp_item_NO) AS MyApp_item_NO ,
        itemStyle.COno       ,
        itemStyle.STAT_DESC       ,
        itemStyle.CUST_CODE       ,
        itemStyle.CUST_NAME       ,
        itemStyle.CUSTCO_NO       ,
        itemStyle.UCUST_CODE      ,
        itemStyle.UCUST_NAME      ,
        itemStyle.DSHIP_FLAG      ,
        itemStyle.STY_NO          ,
        itemStyle.STY_DESC        ,
        itemStyle.BRAND_DESC      ,
        itemStyle.PRODIV_DESC     ,
        itemStyle.CUSTY_DESC      ,
        itemStyle.SEA_DESC        ,
        itemStyle.LINNAMDESC      ,
        itemStyle.SUPP_CODE       ,
    itemStyle.SUPP_NAME,
        itemStyle.CONCEPDESC      ,
        itemStyle.RS_DATE         ,
        itemStyle.ABM_DATE        ,
        VALUE(itemStyle.CS_DATE, CustomsInfo.CS_DATE, SizeInfo.CS_DATE,  OrderChar.CS_Date) AS CS_DATE         ,
        itemStyle.REMARKS         ,
        itemStyle.LASTUPDATE      ,
        itemStyle.FACT_CODE       ,
        itemStyle.C_ORIGIN        ,
        itemStyle.itemDDESC,
        VALUE(itemDELIVERY.DS_NO, SizeInfo.DS_NO,CustomsInfo.DS_NO) AS DS_NO        ,
        itemDELIVERY.CUST_DS_NO   ,
        itemDELIVERY.ULTCUST_DS_NO,
        itemDELIVERY.LCS_DATE     ,
itemDELIVERY.DTERM_DESC   ,
itemSHIPINST.SHIP_MARKS   ,
itemDELIVERY.PACK_INST,
        itemStyle.KEY_SIZE        ,
        itemSHIPINST.SMODE_DESC   ,
        itemSHIPINST.ORIGN_itemRT   ,
        itemSHIPINST.DEST_itemRT    ,
        itemSHIPINST.CARR_DESC    ,
itemSHIPINST.SPL_INST,
        itemStyle.PAYM_DESC       ,
        itemStyle.PAYT_DESC       ,
        itemStyle.UCUSTCO_NO      ,
        itemStyle.ORD_RDATE       ,
        itemStyle.ORG_NAME        ,
        itemStyle.CUSTY_NO        ,
        VALUE(itemDELADDRESS.COMPANY1,'')  AS DELCOMPANY1 ,
        VALUE(itemDELADDRESS.COMPANY2,'')  AS DELCOMPANY2  ,
        VALUE(itemDELADDRESS.COMPANY3,'')   AS DELCOMPANY3  ,
        VALUE(itemDELADDRESS.STREET1,'')    AS DELSTREET1,
        VALUE(itemDELADDRESS.STREET2,'')    AS DELSTREET2,
        VALUE(itemDELADDRESS.STREET3,'')    AS DELSTREET3,
        VALUE(itemDELADDRESS.CITY,'')       AS DELCITY,
        VALUE(itemDELADDRESS.STATENAME,'')  AS DELSTATENAME,
        VALUE(itemDELADDRESS.COUNTRY,'')    AS DELCOUNTRY,
        VALUE(itemDELADDRESS.ZIP_CODE,'')  AS DELZIP ,
        VALUE(itemDELIVERY.itemDEL_SEQ , CustomsInfo.itemDEL_SEQ, SizeInfo.itemDEL_SEQ, OrderChar.itemDEL_SEQ)  AS itemDEL_SEQ ,
        itemStyle.DEBTOR_CODE     ,
        VALUE(itemADDRESS.STATENAME,'') AS STATENAME,
VALUE(itemADDRESS.COMPANY1,'') AS COMPANY1,
VALUE(itemADDRESS.COMPANY2,'') AS COMPANY2,
VALUE(itemADDRESS.COMPANY3,'') AS COMPANY3,
VALUE(itemADDRESS.STREET1,'') AS STREET1,
VALUE(itemADDRESS.STREET2,'') AS STREET2,
VALUE(itemADDRESS.STREET3,'') AS STREET3,
VALUE(itemADDRESS.CITY,'') AS CITY,
VALUE(itemADDRESS.COUNTRY,'') AS itemADDRCOUNTRY,
VALUE(itemADDRESS.ZIP_CODE,'') AS ZIP_CODE,
        itemStyle.CURRENCY        ,
        itemStyle.CREATEDATE      ,
        itemStyle.SIZE_TNAME      ,
        itemStyle.BUSUNIDESC      ,
        VALUE (itemStyle.SIZ1TABID, CustomsInfo.SIZ1TABID, SizeInfo.SIZ1TABID,   OrderChar.SIZ1TABID) AS SIZ1TABID,
        itemStyle.DISC_VALUE      ,
        HSYS_NO, NHSYS_NO       ,
        VALUE(itemColor.COL_NO, SizeInfo.COL_NO, CustomsInfo.COL_NO) AS COL_NO,
        itemColor.PROCH_DESC      ,
        itemColor.PROREQDESC      ,
        itemColor.COL_DESC        ,
        VALUE (itemColor.HAND_CHARGE,0) HAND_CHARGE     ,
        VALUE(itemColor.OTHER_CHARGES, 0) OTHER_CHARGES   ,
        itemColor.PERF_CODE,
        SizeInfo.QUANTITY       ,
        SizeInfo.OCP_FACTOR     ,
        SizeInfo.SKU_CODE       ,
        SizeInfo.SIZE_CODE      ,
        SizeInfo.UNIT_PRC       ,
        SizeInfo.SURCHARGE      ,
        SizeInfo.itemSIZE_NUM     ,
        SizeInfo.UNIT_DISC,
    SizeInfo.CUSIZ_CODE,
    SizeInfo.PACK_UNIT,
        YOUTSOLE.ITMDES AS OUTSOLEDESC, YOUTSOLE.OUTSOLE AS OUTSOLECODE,
/*        (SELECT ITMDES FROM item.YCATEGO YCATEGO WHERE YCATEGO.categoid = art1sty.categoid) AS CategoDesc,
        (SELECT ITMDES FROM item.YACTGRP YACTGRP WHERE YACTGRP.actgrpid = art1sty.actgrpid) AS ACTGRPDesc,*/
        LEADTM_DESC AS LeadTime,
/*        (SELECT SUM(VALUE(hand_charge,0) +  VALUE(other_charges,0)) AS TotalCharge FROM item.itemColor itemColor WHERE itemColor.itemSTY_SEQ = itemStyle.itemSTY_SEQ) AS TotalCharge,*/
        itemDelivery.AMD_Date,
        OrderChar.ordchar_desc,
        YPROCON.ITMDES AS PromotionContract,
        (SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM SizeInfo WHERE SizeInfo.MyApp_item_NO = itemStyle.MyApp_item_NO) AS OrderTotalQty,
        Supp_Address.*,
    Cust_Address.*,
    CASE WHEN 'MyAppitemNo' = 'csDate' THEN VALUE(itemStyle.CS_Date, CustomsInfo.CS_Date, SizeInfo.CS_Date, OrderChar.CS_Date)
             WHEN 'MyAppitemNo' = 'rsDate' THEN VALUE(itemStyle.RS_Date, CustomsInfo.RS_Date,SizeInfo.RS_Date, OrderChar.RS_Date)
         WHEN 'MyAppitemNo' = 'lcsDate' THEN VALUE(itemStyle.CS_Date, CustomsInfo.CS_Date, SizeInfo.CS_Date, OrderChar.CS_Date)
         ELSE '2010-01-01'
        END AS SortDate,
    CASE WHEN 'MyAppitemNo' = 'MyAppitemNo' THEN VALUE(itemStyle.MyApp_item_NO, CustomsInfo.MyApp_item_NO, SizeInfo.MyApp_item_NO, OrderChar.MyApp_item_NO)
         WHEN 'MyAppitemNo' = 'MyAppCoNo' THEN VALUE(itemStyle.COno, CustomsInfo.COno, SizeInfo.COno, OrderChar.COno)
             WHEN 'MyAppitemNo' = 'custCoNo' THEN VALUE(itemStyle.CustCO_NO, CustomsInfo.CustCO_NO, SizeInfo.CustCO_NO, OrderChar.CustCO_NO)
         WHEN 'MyAppitemNo' = 'custCode' THEN VALUE(itemStyle.Cust_Code, CustomsInfo.Cust_Code,SizeInfo.Cust_Code, OrderChar.Cust_Code)
         WHEN 'MyAppitemNo' = 'ucustCoNo' THEN VALUE(itemStyle.UCustCO_NO, CustomsInfo.UCustCO_NO, SizeInfo.UCustCO_NO, OrderChar.UCustCO_NO)
         WHEN 'MyAppitemNo' = 'proDivDesc' THEN VALUE(itemStyle.Prodiv_Desc, CustomsInfo.Prodiv_Desc, SizeInfo.Prodiv_Desc, OrderChar.Prodiv_Desc)
         WHEN 'MyAppitemNo' = 'busUniDesc' THEN VALUE(itemStyle.BUSUNIDESC, CustomsInfo.BusuniDesc, SizeInfo.BusuniDesc, OrderChar.BusuniDesc)
         WHEN 'MyAppitemNo' = 'styNo' THEN VALUE(itemStyle.STY_NO, CustomsInfo.STY_NO, SizeInfo.STY_NO, OrderChar.STY_NO)
         ELSE 'xxx'
        END AS SortField
FROM itemStyle_ AS itemStyle
    INNER JOIN item.itemDELIVERY itemDELIVERY ON itemStyle.itemSTY_SEQ = itemDELIVERY.itemSTY_SEQ
        INNER JOIN item.itemDELCOLOR itemDELCOLOR ON itemDELCOLOR.itemDEL_SEQ = itemDELIVERY.itemDEL_SEQ
        INNER JOIN item.itemColor itemColor ON itemDELCOLOR.itemCOL_SEQ  = itemColor.itemCOL_SEQ
        INNER JOIN item.itemSHIPINST itemSHIPINST ON itemSHIPINST.itemDEL_SEQ = itemDELIVERY.itemDEL_SEQ
        INNER JOIN item.itemDELADDRESS itemDELADDRESS ON itemDELADDRESS.itemDEL_SEQ = itemDELIVERY.itemDEL_SEQ
        INNER JOIN item.itemADDRESS itemADDRESS ON itemADDRESS.itemSTY_SEQ = itemStyle.itemSTY_SEQ
        INNER JOIN item.ART1STY ART1STY ON ART1STY.ART1STYID = itemStyle.ART1STYID
INNER JOIN Supp_Address ON itemStyle.SUPP_ID = Supp_Address.SUP1COMID
INNER JOIN Cust_Address ON itemStyle.CUST_ID = Cust_Address.CustAdd_Cust_ID
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN item.ART4COS ART4COS ON itemColor.ART4COSID = ART4COS.ART4COSID
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN item.ART2STS ART2STS ON  ART2STS.ART2STSID = ART4COS.ART2STSID
                                LEFT JOIN item.YPROCON YPROCON ON ART2STS.PROCONID = YPROCON.PROCONID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN item.YOUTSOLE YOUTSOLE ON YOUTSOLE.OUTSOLEID  = ART1STY.OUTSOLEID
        FULL OUTER JOIN CustomsInfo ON 1=2
        FULL OUTER JOIN SizeInfo ON 1=2
                                FULL OUTER JOIN OrderChar ON 1=2
ORDER BY
SortDate DESC, SortField DESC,
MyApp_item_NO ,
VALUE(DS_NO,0),
VALUE(COL_NO,0),
itemDEL_SEQ,
ReitemrtGrp,
         ReitemrtGrp2 DESC, SizeInfo.itemSIZE_NUM
FOR READ ONLY
```

#### Update:

My DB is having no triggers and procedures

The Strange part is for those set of (300) records query fails but works fine for 1000 rows/records/input parameters. Any Idea.

Comment: You need to post your statement to make it easier for us to suggest something.

Comment: The negative SQLCODEs are generally for compile-time errors, not runtime errors. In particular, it's telling you that your statement is too long or complex. How do you change things to get it to work? Do you change the statement, the parameters, or the data in the tables?

Comment: Very Thanks to Gabe and sjngm

Comment: No Statement remain same only parameters increases.The 2 or third line is commented only changes.For particular set of 300 records is failing and for 1000 and 10000 records it is successfull.

Comment: Did you try to suppress some joins to identify the culprit?

Comment: See I mentioned clearly The same query works for 1000 rows but fails for 300.So something very unusual is associated as we donot use any triggers and procedures in DB.

Comment: I don't think join is the culprit as it is same for 1000 rows too.Right..

Comment: This sounds like a bug. I would contact IBM support to see if they can look into it.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the query statement exceed the default size of 4KB. You can set the statement heap size as the following.

```
db2 update db cfg for YOUR_DATABASE_NAME using STMTHEAP 8192 AUTOMATIC
```